# Json schema validation against Json Object using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I am trying to validate around 100 JSON Objects against a JSON schema to see if all the fields along with the type are as per the schema or not.

Tried below JSON schema which was generated from a site.
The issue with the below schema is that it does not support validation of multiple items for the "files" field as the schema is not completely correct.

Added below schema

```
     var schema ={
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "data": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "contents": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": [
            {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "version": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "sequence": {
                  "type": "integer"
                },
                "files": {
                  "type": "array",
                  "items": [
                    {
                      "type": "object",
                      "properties": {
                        "fileName": {
                          "type": "string"
                        },
                        "name": {
                          "type": "string"
                        },
                        "fileSize": {
                          "type": "string"
                        },
                        "fileType": {
                          "type": "string"
                        },
                        "lastUpdatedDate": {
                          "type": "integer"
                        },
                        "fileLength": {
                          "type": "integer"
                        },
                        "version": {
                          "type": "integer"
                        }
                      },
                      "required": [
                        "fileName",
                        "name",
                        "fileSize",
                        "fileType",
                        "lastUpdatedDate",
                        "fileLength",
                        "version"
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              "required": [
                "version",
                "sequence",
                "files"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "contents"
      ]
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "data"
  ]
}

  var validator = new Validator(schema)

  var json=
  {
      "data": {
          "contents": [
              {
                  "versionn": "2021-01-15T16:01:13.475Z",
                  "sequence": 1,
                  "files": [
                      {
                          "fileName": "us-producer-price-index.txt",
                          "name": "us-producer-price-index",
                          "fileSize": "54MB",
                          "fileType": "txt",
                          "lastUpdatedDate": 1610717473000,
                          "fileLength": 56614933,
                          "version": 2
                      }
                  ]
              }
          ]
      }
  };

  var check = validator.check(json);
   
  console.log(check);

  if(check._error==true)
  {
      console.log("Error in schema")
  }
```

Comment: Your JSON is invalid.

Comment: @RichardRublev the schema is invalid? Could you please suggest the change

Comment: Check with https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#

Comment: @RichardRublev added valid schema , still same output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that what you want is to apply the same validation rule for all the items in your array.

Schema provides [list validation](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/array.html#id5) and [tuple validation](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/array.html#id6). The **list** validation is specified as **a schema**, apply the same rule for any item in the array, the **tuple** is specified as an **array of schemas** and validate `item[i]` against `schema.item[i]`.

Notice that your `items` schemas is an array of one element. This means that only the first element is validated against your schema. What I assume you want instead is this schema.

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "data": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "contents": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "version": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "sequence": {
                "type": "integer"
              },
              "files": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                  "type": "object",
                  "properties": {
                    "fileName": {
                      "type": "string"
                    },
                    "name": {
                      "type": "string"
                    },
                    "fileSize": {
                      "type": "string"
                    },
                    "fileType": {
                      "type": "string"
                    },
                    "lastUpdatedDate": {
                      "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "fileLength": {
                      "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "version": {
                      "type": "integer"
                    }
                  },
                  "required": [
                    "fileName",
                    "name",
                    "fileSize",
                    "fileType",
                    "lastUpdatedDate",
                    "fileLength",
                    "version"
                  ]
                }
              }
            },
            "required": [
              "version",
              "sequence",
              "files"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "contents"
      ]
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "data"
  ]
}
```

### Additional examples

In order to illustrate the how the array validation works I created a snipped that is very enlightening.

```js
const Ajv = window.ajv7.default;
const ajv = new Ajv({strict: false});

function dumpJson(item){
  const el = document.createElement('pre');
  el.textContent = typeof(item) === 'string' ? item :  JSON.stringify(item)
  document.body.appendChild(el);
  return el;
}

function Test(schema, title){
  const validate = ajv.compile(schema)
  if(title)dumpJson(title).classList.add('title')
  dumpJson(JSON.stringify(schema, null, 2))
  const tester = {
    with: (item) => {
      const el = dumpJson(item)
      if(validate(item)){
        el.classList.add('valid');
      }else{
        el.classList.add('invalid');
      }
      return tester
    }
  }
  return tester;
}

Test({
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  type: 'array', items: [{type: 'number'}, {type: 'string'}]
}, 'tuple validation: [number]')
.with([0])
.with([0, 1])
.with([0, "a"])
.with([0, "a", {}, [], null, false, true])
Test({
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  type: 'array', items: [{type: 'number'}]
}, 'tuple validation: [number, string]')
.with([0])
.with([0, 1])
.with([0, "a"])
.with([0, "a", {}, [], null, false, true])

Test({
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  type: 'array', items: {type: 'number'}
}, 'list validation: number[]')
.with([0])
.with([0, 1])
.with([0, "a"])
.with([0, "a", {}, [], null, false, true])


Test({
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  type: 'array', items: [{type: 'number'}, {type: 'string'}]
}, 'tuple validation: [number, string]')
.with([0])
.with([0, 1])
.with([0, "a"])
.with([0, "a", {}, [], null, false, true])

Test({
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  type: 'array', items: {'anyOf': [{type: 'number'}, {type: 'string'}]}
}, 'list validation: (number|string)[]')
.with([0])
.with([0, 1])
.with([0, "a"])
.with([0, "a", {}, [], null, false, true])
.with(['a', 'b', 'c'])
.with(['a', 0])
.with(['a', 0, false])
```

```css
.valid {
  margin-left: 20px; color: green;
}
.invalid {
  margin-left: 20px; color: red;
}
.title {
  font-size: 2em;
}

body: {
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ajv/7.1.1/ajv7.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

While your JSON Schema is "valid", it doesn't express any constraints.

you have missed the need to use the `properties` keyword.

> The value of "properties" MUST be an object.  Each value of this
> object MUST be a valid JSON Schema.
>
> Validation succeeds if, for each name that appears in both the
> instance and as a name within this keyword's value, the child
> instance for that name successfully validates against the
> corresponding schema.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-02#section-9.3.2.1

In order to apply a subschema to an object, you need to use the `properties` keyword. Like this...

```
{
  "required": ["data"],
  "properties": {
    "data": {
      "type": "object"
    }
  }
}
```

This requirement applies for each subschema too. Unknown keywords are ignored, so `data` at the root of the schema was simply ignored, resulting in no constraints being expressed.

You may find it helpful to review the JSON Schema getting started guide: http://json-schema.org/learn/

---

Update:
After adding an update to your question in the form of an answer, it looks like the generator is almost right, but not quite.

When using the `items` keyword pre draft 2020-12, array values apply subschemas items to the same index location only. If you want the subschema value to apply to all items in the applicable array, you need to use a schema object as the value as opposed to an array of schema values.

> The value of "items" MUST be either a valid JSON Schema or an array
> of valid JSON Schemas.
>
> If "items" is a schema, validation succeeds if all elements in the
> array successfully validate against that schema.
>
> If "items" is an array of schemas, validation succeeds if each
> element of the instance validates against the schema at the same
> position, if any.

JSON Schema draft 2019-09 - https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-02#section-9.3.1.1

I refer you to our getting started guide, as linked above, which covers this. If you expect to maintain your schemas, it would be worth reading.

Comment: Thanks, I think you have my answer :) I did add the properties key too but it doesnt seem to make any change to the out. Request if you can add the schema for my json to help me understand. Thanks

Comment: If you have modified your schema and it still doesn't work, you should look at updating your question to ADD the new schema. If I can't see the full new schema, I'm not sure how to help you.

Comment: I have now modified my question. Only confused on how handle properties for sub section of json

Comment: I can see you have updated your question. It looks like you didn't follow my suggestion of using the `properties` keyword. You've also posted your own answer, in which you can see how you need to use the `properties` keyword at each subschema where you want to apply subschemas to more property values. The schema generator you've used has resulted in a very old (draft-04) schema. If `contents` or `files` can have multiple items in the array values, then the schema is also wrong, and won't do what you want.

Comment: I agree to your statement, could you please modify my schema so that files can handle multiple items in the array and I could mark your answer as the correct answer here. Would help a lot if you did. thanks

Comment: I can help, but you should ADD your updated schema to your question. Please do not simply replace the schema in your question. Your questions and the answers should be helpful to OTHERS, not just yourself.

Comment: Yup,I totally agree. I have now updated the question

Comment: You have either not read or not understood my comment. It now looks like my answer is totally wrong given your question because you didn't keep your initial schema/problem.

Comment: My bad, I am honestly trying to do this the correct way. If at all it does help you could modify your answer and I could mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: That's OK. Just explaining. I have updated my question to try and make it a little clearer. That should give you all you need.

Comment: Is there anything lacking here or can you accept an answer? =]